# Viewport based window manager?

Tags: linux, window-manager

Currently I use AwesomeWM for a tiling window-manager. I love it. However I am getting a 4k monitor (3840×2160, that's like 4 1080p screens together). I think that with this screen it would make more sense to divide my screen into smaller viewports, with windows that tile inside each.   Out of the box, AwesomeWM does not seem to have this functionality.

I am a developer, so if nothing that meets my needs exists I am not opposed to looking at XCB and attempting to write my own solution... but I would prefer not to use my limited time doing so. If there is an existing solution I would love to see it.

Ultimately I would like to be able to define a custom grid of viewports, and open any number of windows within that tile according to scheme. Even better if I can set up these viewports then launch AwesomeWM and have it launch within each one (the way it does if you have multiple monitors, but in this case different viewports). Oh, I also want to be able to dynamically resize the viewports and have the others adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at CLFSWM? It is hierarchical tiling wm, each frame can contain any other frames (windows), and each of them could be the current root (fullscreen window)

Here some of it's features are shown: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jv0UQR-5ZLs